# Show progress using Ajax on a flask program

Tags: python, ajax, multithreading, flask, flask-wtforms

I created a web application to process large amounts of data using python flask framework. I created a form and I get the input parameters for the data consuming program when the user submits the form. The program takes about 20-30 mins to complete and I'd like to show the status of the program to the user in a webpage.

How do I achieve this?

After the user submits the data, do I need to run the program on a separate thread and redirect to a success page on a different thread? How do I communicate between the program and the POST page? How do I refresh the page at continuous intervals?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

For tasks that are too long-lived to exist entirely within the request/response cycle, task queues are a good option. Check out [celery](http://www.celeryproject.org/).

You can string together tasks to update your app's state when your task is finished, then poll your app with [setInterval()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval) and [clearInterval()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/clearInterval) browser APIs.

Answer (score 1):

I happened to have done the same thing several months ago. The code is [here](https://github.com/laike9m/EasyMerge). Basically you use Celery+rabbitmq to run your task in background. Hope it helps.